# The zeroth argument to a command executed by exec

Tags: bash, exec

From Bash Manual

> ```
> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
> ```
>
> If command is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new
>   process.
>
> **If the `-l` option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument passed to `command`. This is what the
>   login program does.**
>
> **If `-a` is supplied, the shell passes `name` as the zeroth argument to `command`.**

Without `-l` or `-a` what is in the zeroth argument passed to `command`?

What is the purpose of `-l` placing a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument?

What is the purpose of `-a` passing `name` as the beginning of the zeroth argument?

I tried to experiment. Why does the first experiment not output anything, while the second outputs `bash`?

```
$ bash; exec echo $0 

$ bash; 
$  exec 'echo' $0 
bash
```

Comment: I get "bash" output in *both* of your examples; is that your actual session output?  What do you mean by "without `-l` or `-a` what is the ... argument ... *like*" ? It it *like* an elephant, or is it *like* a string or it *like* a bunch of bytes? What are we comparing it to? Would strace output clarify your understanding?

Answer (score 4):

> Without `-l` or `-a` what is the zeroth argument passed to command like?

In this case the zeroth argument is just `command` itself.

> What is the purpose of -l placing a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument?

It's a convention that most (all?) shells respect. When a login session is started, the shell is started with a hyphen in front of its zeroth argument (placed there by `login` or whatever launched the session) and the shell interprets this as a signal to start a new login session.

> What is the purpose of `-a` passing `name` as the beginning of the zeroth argument?

It's the only way of setting a zeroth argument that is [substantially] different from the pathname or filename that was used to actually start the process. The reason you might want to do this is that a few commands check their zeroth argument to see how they should behave. You can also use this to fool a program into thinking it was launched from a different pathname than it actually was (this might help it find its data files, for example).

```
$ bash; exec echo $0
```

This is a bit of a strange command. The `echo` will certainly output something (and then immediately terminate your session), but not until the subshell that you launch first terminates. What exactly are you trying to test/achieve here?

If you wanted to test the functionality, you'd do:

```
$ strace -fe execve bash -c 'exec -a foo echo test'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "exec -a foo echo test"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
execve("/bin/echo", ["foo", "test"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
test
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ strace -fe execve bash -c 'exec -l echo test'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "exec -l echo test"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
execve("/bin/echo", ["-echo", "test"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
test
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ (exec -a uname busybox)
Linux
$ (exec -l bash -c 'echo "$0"')
-bash
$ (exec -l ksh -c '[ -o login ] && echo yes')
yes
```

(with `exec -l bash -c ...` (or `bash -lc ...`), bash does read the `~/.bash_profile`, but otherwise doesn't consider itself a login shell).