# How can we start bash with the first character of argument zero being ‘-’?

Tags: bash, login

Bash manual says:

> A login shell is one **whose first character of argument zero is ‘-’**, or one invoked with the --login option.

However, I was wonderying why I have the following error?

```
$ -bash
No command '-bash' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rbash' from package 'bash' (main)
 Command 'bash' from package 'bash' (main)
-bash: command not found
```

How can we  start bash with the first character of argument zero being ‘-’?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With Bash:

```
exec -a -bash bash
```

With Zsh:

```
ARGV0=-bash bash # or ARGV0=-bash exec bash
```

Comment: With the caveat, on the Bash variant, that the current shell is replaced with the new one. And funnily enough Tim [already knew the answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435625/does-a-noninteractive-login-shell-execute-profile-or-a-file-whose-name-is/435626?noredirect=1#comment786884_435626).

Comment: Thanks. Why do   I have the command not found error?

Comment: because you don't have a command named `-bash`. the documentation that you quoted, then bolded mentioned the `ARGV0` of the bash process starting with `-`, not the command name.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382984/ from 2017.